# How to make relative layout add elements in a horizontal direction?

Tags: html, css

Why are relative elements added vertically, in a column. Is it possible to have elements displayed horizontally instead of vertically? Like a row instead of a column.

Comment: if someone is down-grading the question, at least tell whats wrong?

Comment: You are getting downvoted for not searching before asking a question. It is quite a basic question. If you hover over the downvote button one of the criteria is "does not show any research effort". If you were unable to find solutions through a google or other search please include that and your search terms in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the position to relative doesnt necessarily dictate order in terms of horzontal vs vertical placing. This is the difference between block level and inline elements.

Block level elements (e.g. `div`) display on a new line by default, `inline` elements (e.g. `span`) appear on the same line, if the available width allows it.

You can see this in [**effect here**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Tn38f/)

You can override the default `display` for elements by setting it in your CSS.

[**More on Block level elements from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

> "Block-level" is categorization of HTML (Hypertext Markup Language)
>   elements, as contrasted with "inline" elements. Block-level elements
>   may appear only within a  element. Their most significant
>   characteristic is that they typically are formatted with a line break
>   before and after the element (thereby creating a stand-alone block of
>   content). That is, they take up the width of their containers.

[**More on Inline elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente)

> "Inline" is categorization of HTML elements, as contrasted with
>   "block-level" elements. Inline elements can appear within block-level
>   or other inline elements. They take up the width of their contents.
>   The differences between inline and block-level elements include [...] formatting, by default, inline elements do not begin with new line.

Comment: @user274951 no problem, dont forget to mark as accepted whichever answer helps the most- whether this or another

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the `display:inline-block` CSS property. By default, elements are displayed using `display:block` which is the reason for them displaying like a "column".

Try this as an example.

**HTML:**

```
<div>Relative Div 1</div>
<div>Relative Div 2</div>
<div>Relative Div 3</div>
```

**CSS: (added some lines to make it more visible as to what it's doing.)**

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ff0000;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gJptj/)**

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear...maybe your elements are in default display (display:block). You can try put display: inline-block in your elements.

example:

```
  <style>
  .whatever{display:inline-block;}
  </style>

  <div class="whatever">....</div>
  <div class="whatever">....</div>
  <div class="whatever">....</div>
  <div class="whatever">....</div>
```