# Add element to horizontal layout without fitting to container

Tags: css, polymer

I'm trying to add X elements to a horizontal layout.
My goal is to show a horizontal scroll bar as soon as the elements exceed the viewport width.

I'm following the docs:

- https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html
- https://material.angularjs.org/#/layout/grid

But elements are being shrank to fit the viewport, although I'm not using `fullbleed` parameter.

I've seen also this [question relative to .css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562004/how-to-make-relative-layout-add-elements-in-a-horizontal-direction).

I've also try adding specific `width`, without success.

[Plunker to reproduce it](http://plnkr.co/edit/zSvUIA?p=preview).

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
<div id="container" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: auto;">
  <div ng-repeat="item in divElements" style="border:solid 1px red; display: inline-block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a min-width: 100px, or any number, so it does not shrink them to fit.
http://plnkr.co/edit/551uhyalZaF94AP8Mh1O?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="item in divElements" style="border:solid 1px red; min-width: 100px;">
  Created at: {{item.createdAt}}<br>
  <big-div></big-div>
</div>
```